# unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, indentation

i wrote the following python code but i can't see what is the cause of the problem but i get the following error message:

def   post(self):
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write(form)
    
def post(self):
    self.response.out.write("valid")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],debug=True)
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your code example is riddled with TAB characters. If you are mixing tabs with spaces, the error is almost a given.

Use the [python `tabnanny`](http://docs.python.org/library/tabnanny.html) to clean up your source-code, switch your editor to use spaces only, then fix your indentations:

```
python -m tabnanny -v path/to/your/code.py
```

Comment: thank very much i managed to solve the issue i was mixing tab and spaces

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up spaces and tabs. Run the script in `python -tt` to verify.